# How can I get my navigation bar to span the full width of the page?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

When I scroll down, my buttons are fixed (great), but the navigation bar doesn't span the whole page (nav bar should be white). How do I fix this?

Also how do I get my "active" bar to become inactive upon scroll over (the opposite of the other buttons)?

I'm using bootstrap and I'm a new programmer, so please ELI5.

```css
#header {
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  padding: 20px;
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a {
  color: black;
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > .active > a {
  color: white;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li> a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
        <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one and give your feedback

```css
#header {
  padding: 10px;
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
  padding: 20px;
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a {
  color: black;
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > .active > a {
 
  color: white;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
  
}
.navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li> a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #E74C3C;
}

  

 .navbar #nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right > li{
     float:left;
     margin-right:80px;
     list-style:none;
    }
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
        <div class="nav-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```